# The UART driver of bootloader can only be used for bootloader, but not for Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, uart, bootloader, u-boot

I am writing a driver for uart16750 for bbl(Berkeley Boot Loader)，and our cpu can boot bbl, but there is nothing print when boot linux kernel. So my question is the uart16750 driver in bbl is only used for bbl, cannot used for linux kernel?

Comment: The Linux kernel uses its own drivers.

Comment: And 16750 is supported by Linux kernel for ages.